# bootstrap, pre height of container element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi im having issues laying out a html pre to be the height of the container element in twitter-bootstrap. Currently the i have tried a few methods to solve the problem i found on stack-overflow however the few that worked resulted in the div actually overflowing over the container element:

```
<container>
<h2 class='text-center'>continer content</h2><hr/><pre style='bottom: 0;position: absolute;height:100%;overflow-y: scroll;'>
</container>
```

This resulted in pre element becoming the size of the page and flowing over the container element.

```
<container>
<h2 class='text-center'>container content</h2><hr/><div class="col-xs-10 fh" style="background: black;"><pre style='overflow-y: scroll;'></div>
</container>
```

This method did not result in any changes at all to the presentation of the content either and remained just 100% to fit the content inside the pre tag rather than filling the container. Is there a simple way to stretch the pre tag to fill bootstraps container element?

Note that i have tried a number of ways and the only one im reluctant to try is editing bootstraps css so container has this attribute:

```
display: flex;

For childs:

align-items: stretch;
```

As i would prefer not to modify bootstraps css file. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want the `<pre>` element to fill the entire height of the container, with the h2 visible on top of the `<pre>` element?

Comment: Either way would be fine my biggest problem is i just cant get the pre element to fill the entire container with the header above or inside the pre element. thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can most simply be achieved by using `position: absolute;` on the `<pre>` element and `position: relative;` on the containing element, then setting `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` on the `<pre>` element.

See for more detail: http://jsbin.com/wurufo/edit?html,css,output

Note: I have made some amendments to your HTML because I'm not sure what your intention is by using `<container>` as an HTML element. Also, I have taken steps to ensure the `<h2>` appears over the `<pre>` because I'm not 100% certain what your goal was there.